# Cleric archtype crusader legions blessing and making it useful

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, cleric, archetype

Im building a cleric and was considering the [crusader archtype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/archetypes/paizo---cleric-archetypes/crusader) except that I dont know if its useful.

Its the ability at 8th level called legions blessing which has me both interested and unsure.

> At 8th level, a crusader gains the ability to confer beneficial spells quickly to a large group of allies. As a full-round action, the crusader may confer the effects of a single harmless spell with a range of touch to a number of creatures equal to half her cleric level. The spell’s range remains touch, so all intended recipients must be within the crusader’s reach when the spell is cast. Using the legion’s blessing expends the prepared spell, but it also requires the crusader to sacrifice another prepared spell three levels higher, as when spontaneously using a cure or inflict spell. The higher-level spell is not cast but is simply lost, its magical energy used to power the legion’s blessing.

Most of the spells that I can think of which are touch and harmless have a mass version of the spell. So what spells are there that would make this ability useful?

Comment: Do you want the list of spells that might be useful for this ability or you prefer a situation where this can be useful? The first one might be too taxing and might not yield results, the second one is, at least doable since I already see one possible scenario (but I'm not an expert in pathfinder, so I can't help too much).

Comment: Im just trying to find out if people know of any spells which are touch and harmless which do not have a mass version. I know this could be a very usable ability, its just that offhand I dont know of any non-mass spells which could increase that

Comment: Seriously, I want to know what is so complicated about the question that it has to be put on hold... it's really straightforward to me.

Comment: @FlashRebel - The close reason says it: `There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format`.  In this case, there are *probably* a long list of valid answers, but ["list questions" are not allowed on Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/165591).  Any answer would also become outdated as soon as another book came out, so it could never be complete.

Comment: Not looking for a whole list, just a couple of spells which show the ability is useful